# port knocking doesn't work under windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, port, knockd

We have been using a program called knock.exe successfully under Windows XP to knock on some set of ports which will then allow a connection to be established via ssh on another port to a remote machine.  This program worked fine under Windows XP, but under Windows 7 it takes a lot longer to run (gives no error messages) and I am unable to connect to the remote machine.

If i run knock.exe inside a VM not running Windows 7 then connect using SSH from the Windows 7 machine, then it works.

Note that when running the port knocking application from Windows 7, the events get through to the remote machine because there is logging with the ip address of the local machine on the remote machine running knockd (linux).

I have also tried using knock7 from sourceforge with no success.

I have tried many other variations such as setting compatibility mode, and other port knocking applications with no success.

It seems like this is a change in the Windows 7 behaviour (possibly introduced in Vista) from the Windows XP behaviour.

It would be better to not have to run a VM just to do port knocking.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a copy of knock7? The files on sourceforge are corrupted. Both Source and Binary are corrupted. So I can't test it.

Comment: not any more.  I think this has to do with Windows considering partially open ports (those used by port knocking) as a security risk.

Answer (score -1):

use cygwin version of knock.exe